# AWS SDK S3 example giving network error

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems, aws-sdk

I am trying to learn to use the AWS SDK for Ruby, and I started by running the sample programs on S3. But the S3 example gives me this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:318:in 'return_or_raise':AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError (AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:419:in 'client_request'
from (eval):3:in 'put_object'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:1655:in 'write_with_put_object'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:600:in 'write'
from s3/upload_file.rb:31:in 'main'
```

I have already checked using `s3cmd` and it is working fine.

I am using Ruby 1.9.1 and AWS SDK version is 1.8.0.

Comment: You need to post an example of the code you're using. Without that we're guessing what you wrote, which won't do any good.

Comment: I have not written any code I am just running the samples that come with aws-sdk-ruby.

Comment: Then summarize that code, showing the line that causes the problem. Don't make us chase down code just to help you. Ask yourself, what would you need to see to help answer this question, and provide it. We don't get paid and we all use our free time, so help us help you. The more work you do to provide information about the problem, the faster you'll get an answer.